# Problema con String en Java usando Scanner

Tags: java

Estoy teniendo un problema con este código. Yo quiero hacer que el usuario la respuesta "si", después le pida un numero. El problema es que al preguntarle de nuevo "Mas datos?" no te deja ingresar el string de nuevo y no vuelve a repetir el while.

**Mi código:**

```
import java.util.*;

public class MaximoLibro {

    public static void main(String[]args){

        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE; // es el Low Value
        int dato;
        boolean hubo = false;
        String resp;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Quiere ingresar algo?");
        resp = input.nextLine();
        while (resp.equals("si")){
            hubo = true;
            System.out.println("Ingrese dato");
            dato = input.nextInt();
            if (dato > max){
                max = dato;
            }
            System.out.println("Mas datos?");
            resp = input.nextLine();
        }
        if (hubo){
            System.out.println("Maximo vale "+max);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("No hubo datos");
        }
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Cuando se pide un String y después un int,float etc, hay datos basura en el buffer. tienes que vaciar el buffer antes de seguir pidiendo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es con `.nextInt()`. Cuando ingresas un número y presionas "Enter", `.nextInt()` consume solamente el número y no el final de la línea. El final de toda línea es `\n`. Por lo tanto, cuando ejecutas `.nextLine()` consumes el "final de la línea" y estarás listo para leer el siguiente `String` que necesites.

**Puedes resolver este problema con una de estas dos formas:**

1. Agregar un `.nextLine()` extra, entre `.nextInt()` y `.nextLine()`. El `.nextLine()` extra consumirá el "final de la línea" siempre.

**Ejemplo:**

```
int number = scanner.nextInt();
scanner.nextLine(); // Consume "\n"
String string1 = scanner.nextLine();
```

2. Otra forma es utilizar `.nextLine()` en lugar de `.nextInt()` para leer el número. Recuerda que `.nextLine()` consume siempre "el final de la línea". Dado que `.nextLine()` retorna un `String`, tienes que convertir ese `String` a `Integer`. Cómo?, usando `Integer.parseInt(...)`.

**Ejemplo:**

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
```

Si usas la segunda forma, puedes recibir una `Exception` del método `Integer.parseInt(...)` si el `String` que le pasas como argumento no puede ser convertido a `Integer`. Por ejemplo, si le pasas "HolaMundo" y tratas de convertir ese String a Integer, obviamente no se va a poder. Para manejar esas excepciones, deberás usar un bloque `try-catch`. Por esta razón, asegurate que si usas esta forma, el valor ingresado siempre sea un número. Otra ventaja de esta forma es que no tienes que preocuparte de hacer `.nextLine()` cada vez que quieras leer un `INT`.

**Tu código arreglado usando la primera solución:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE; // es el Low Value
        int dato;
        boolean hubo = false;
        String resp;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Quiere ingresar algo?");
        resp = input.nextLine();

        while (resp.equals("si")) {
            hubo = true;
            System.out.println("Ingrese dato");
            dato = input.nextInt();

            input.nextLine(); // Consume "\n"

            if (dato > max) {
                max = dato;
            }
            System.out.println("Mas datos?");
            resp = input.nextLine();
        }

        if (hubo) {
            System.out.println("Maximo vale " + max);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No hubo datos");
        }
        input.close();
    }
```