# Cómo puedo insertar espacios en cadenas

Tags: java

> **Descripción:**
>
> Escribir un programa que lea lineas, y los imprima invirtiendo el
>   orden de los caracteres de la frase.
>
> **Entrada:**
>
> La entrada consiste en un número natural N, seguido de N lineas.
>
> **Salida:**
>
> Imprima, línea por linea, las lineas con los caracteres invertidos.

Ejemplo Entrada:

- `3`
- `hola`
- `toma refresco`
- `que tal`

Ejemplo Salida:

- `aloh`
- `ocserfer amot`
- `lat euq`

Necesito que la barra de espacio forme parte de la cadena. Mi código es este:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class EjercPalabr {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String v[]=new String [1010]; 
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        String c ;

        for(int i=0;i<=n-1;i++) {
            v[i]=sc.next(  );
        }

        for(int j=0;j<=n-1;j++) {
            c=v[j]; 

            for (int k=c.length()-1;0<=k;k--) {
                System.out.print(c.charAt(k));
            }

            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Te hacía falta algunas cosas:

1. Usar `nextLine()` en lugar de `next()`. Usar `next()` solo devolverá lo que viene antes de un espacio. Por otro lado, `nextLine()` devolverá toda la línea, incluyendo espacios.
2. Las condiciones dentro del `for` no eran las correctas. Si ingreso el número 4, solamente podría ingresar 3 palabras y no 4, ya que le estás restando 1, o es algo a propósito?. En fin, lo he corregido.
3. Cerrar el `Scanner`.
4. Un salto de línea se hace con `"\n"`.
5. Cuando lees un número con `sc.nextInt();`, seguido debes hacer
   `sc.nextLine();` para leer el final de la línea y no tengas problemas en la próxima lectura. Puedes leer más
   sobre esto aquí:
   [Problema con String en Java usando Scanner](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/155772/problema-con-string-en-java-usando-scanner/155779#155779)

**Código resuelto:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String v[] = new String[1010];

        System.out.print("Número de palabras: ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine(); // Consume "\n"
        String c;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print("Palabra [" + (i + 1) + "]: ");
            v[i] = sc.nextLine(); // Mejor nextLine() en lugar de next()
        }

        // Cerrar Scanner
        sc.close();

        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            c = v[j];

            // Salto de línea
            System.out.print("\n");

            for (int k = c.length() - 1; 0 <= k; k--) {
                System.out.print(c.charAt(k));
            }

        }

    }
```

**Resultado:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]