# Imprime dos veces "Ingrese el nombre del alumno" dentro del ciclo for

Tags: java

Necesito que pregunte el nombre de alumnos despues de haberse declarado la cantidad de alumnos, pero al ingresar la cantidad no me permite ingresar el nombre del primer alumno y me resta una vuelta del ciclo, por ejemplo: si pongo que tengo 5 alumnos solo me deja escribir 4 y el primero esta vacio ¿Como podria solucionar eso?

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cali{
 public static void main(String args[]){

  int cantidad = 0;
  int calificacion = 0;
  String alumno = "";

  Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de alumnos");
  cantidad = user.nextInt();

  System.out.println("");

  int alumnos[] = new int[cantidad];
  int calificaciones[] = new int[cantidad];
  String nombres[] = new String[cantidad];

  for(int i = 0; i < alumnos.length; i++)
 {
   System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del alumno: ");
   alumno = user.nextLine();
   nombres[i] = alumno;  
 }

  System.out.println("");

  for(int i = 0; i < alumnos.length; i++)
 { 
   System.out.print("Ingrse la calificacion del alumno(a) " + nombres[i] + ":");
   calificacion = user.nextInt();
   calificaciones[i] = calificacion;
 }

 System.out.println("");

  for(int i = 0; i < alumnos.length; i++)
 {
  if(calificaciones[i] <= 5)
   {
    System.out.println("El(La) alumno(a) " + nombres[i] + " reprobo con: " + calificaciones[i]);
   } else if(calificaciones[i] == 10) 
     {
    System.out.println("El(La) alumno(a) " + nombres[i] + " aprobo con una excelente calficacion de " + calificaciones[i]);
     } else
       {
    System.out.println("El(La) alumno(a) " + nombres[i] + " aprobo con: " + calificaciones[i]);
       }
 }

 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que cuando solicitas la cantidad de alumnos, luego llamas al método `user.nextInt()` para obtener dicha cantidad. Hasta aquí todo correcto, siempre y cuando realmente introduzcas un número entero y no otra cosa. Luego empiezas a solicitar los nombres de los alumnos y para obtenerlos utilizas el método `user.nextLine()`, lo que la primera vez que lo llames te devolverá una cadena vacía. Esto ocurre porque cuando introduces un número en la consola y luego das enter, este enter se traduce en un caracter de fin de línea que el método `user.nextInt()` omite en su lectura, pero se queda en el buffer y por eso al intentar leer una nueva línea, obtienes la cadena vacía. Solucionarlo es muy simple, agrega una llamada a `user.nextLine()` justo después del `user.nextInt()`.

```
System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de alumnos");
cantidad = user.nextInt();
user.nextLine();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Estoy empezando en esto y la verdad es que me ayudo y me aclaro mis dudas. Gracias!

Comment: Un placer poder ayudarte. Saludos!!

Answer (score 1):

El problema es con `.nextInt()`. Cuando ingresas un número y presionas "Enter", `.nextInt()` consume solamente el número y no el final de la línea. El final de toda línea es `\n`. Por lo tanto, cuando ejecutas `.nextLine()` consumes el "final de la línea" y estarás listo para leer el siguiente `String` que necesites.

Hay dos formas de solucionar esto, he explicado cómo en el siguiente enlace: [Problema con String en Java usando Scanner](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/155772/problema-con-string-en-java-usando-scanner/155779#155779)

**Solución rápida a tu problema:** Agregar un `.nextLine()` extra, entre `.nextInt()` y `.nextLine()`. El `.nextLine()` extra consumirá el "final de la línea" siempre.

**Código arreglado:**

```
System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de alumnos");
cantidad = user.nextInt();

// Consume "\n"
user.nextLine();
```