# ¿Se repite dos veces una instrucción en la primera vuelta de un ciclo for, cuando solo debería ejecutarse una sola vez?

Tags: java

Lo que pasa es cuando compila la  parte del primer bucle "for", en la primera vuelta me imprime dos veces el método print con los siguientes caracteres "Que valor deseas aguardar en el indice numero #" + (i+1) + " :", despues de la primer vuelta(osea, la segunda) ya no lo imprime dos veces, ¿que es lo que tengo que hacer para que en la primer vuelta no me imprima dos veces, si solamente quiero una?. Cabe mencionar que cuando utilizo variables de tipo entero (int) en los arrays no sucedes esto, solamente pasa con datos de tipo String.

```
package Aborto3;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Aborto3{

 public static void main (String args[]){

 int longitud = 0;
 Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.print("Dame el numero de elementos del vector: ");
  longitud = entrada.nextInt();

  String caracteres[] = new String [longitud];

  for( int i = 0; i < caracteres.length; i++ ){
    System.out.print("Que valor deseas aguardar en el indice numero #" + (i+1) + " :");
    caracteres[i] = entrada.nextLine();
  }

   for( int i = 0; i < caracteres.length; i++){
   System.out.print("[" + caracteres[i] + "]");
  } 
 }
}
```

Comment: [Aqui lo explican bastante bien](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/155772/problema-con-string-en-java-usando-scanner/)

Answer (score 1):

Debes usar el método [.next()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) en lugar de .nextLine() :

```
  ...
  ...
  for( int i = 0; i < caracteres.length; i++ ){
    System.out.print("Que valor deseas aguardar en el indice numero #" + (i+1) + " :");
    caracteres[i] = entrada.next();
  }
  ...
  ...
```

La razón es que si usas `nextLine()` mueve automáticamente el escáner hacia abajo después de devolver la línea actual.

Comment: Perdon, no entendi muy bien la parte en donde mencionas que el escáner se mueve hacia abajo después de devolver la linea actual, , segun yo todavía no habria razon para moverse hacia abajo si todavia ni utilizo el nextline() ni el next(), en pocas palabras, todavía ni utilizo  el escáner,¿o realmente no es así?, es que apenas soy novato en esto, perdon por tantas dudas

Comment: @OscarIvanLopez usas nextLine() aquí :  caracteres[i] = entrada.nextLine(); cambia a .next();

Answer (score 1):

El problema esta que al pedir una variable `int`

```
longitud = entrada.nextInt();
```

Cuando se introducen valores numéricos (de cualquier tipo) con los métodos `nextInt`, `nextDouble`, etc. deja el carácter `n` o `enter` en el **buffer**, por lo tanto, cuando se quiere leer una cadena con el método `nextLine()`, esta función inicia la lectura del **buffer** ¡y lo primero que se encuentra es justamente el carácter de final de cadena! ( `n` ), es ahí cuando el flujo salta a la siguiente linea, y aunque pensamos que no se leyó nada, si se leyó dicho carácter.

Por la tanto para solucionar tu problema tendríamos que limpiar dicho **buffer** de la siguiente manera:

```
entrada.nextLine();//Limpiar el buffer de entrada
```

En tu código quedaría así:

```
package Aborto3;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Aborto3{

    public static void main (String args[]){

        int longitud = 0;
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Dame el numero de elementos del vector: ");
        longitud = entrada.nextInt();
        entrada.nextLine();//Limpiar el buffer de entrada

        String caracteres[] = new String [longitud];

        for( int i = 0; i < caracteres.length; i++ ){
            System.out.print("Que valor deseas aguardar en el indice numero #" + (i+1) + " :");
            caracteres[i] = entrada.nextLine();
        }

        for( int i = 0; i < caracteres.length; i++){
            System.out.print("[" + caracteres[i] + "]");
        } 
    }
}
```